# C++ templates and basic data types

Tags: c++

Is there any way to tell if a template parameter is a specific base data type like int or unsigned int?  std::is_base_of doesn't do it, tried that.  I'd like to write collections that can box all the basic data types but I can't find a way to tell which type it is...

Comment: You might want is_integral: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458510/how-to-check-that-templates-parameter-type-is-integral

Comment: Is this a bad question? why downvote?

Comment: Basic data types do not require boxing in C++

Comment: no you don't need it but can be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use is_same.  If you don't have an implementation (std or boost) then use this:

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
struct is_same { enum { value = false }; };

template < typename T >
struct is_same <T,T> { enum { value = true }; };
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation!  Do you guys have this code just laying around or what??

Comment: Given enough time and practice you'll know this one like the back of your hand.

Answer (score 2):

Some useful ones:

[`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)

[`std::is_floating_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point)

[`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic)

If you need some more narrow definiton, you can OR several [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) traits together, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_int_or_char_or_float {
    static const bool value =
        std::is_same<T, int>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, char>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, float>::value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether it is of a specific type, you could use [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
#include <type_traits>

bool isInt = std::is_same<int, T>::value;
```

If you wanted to know whether it is any integral type, the [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)

```
bool isInt = std::is_integral<T>::value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class someClass { };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a;
    someClass b;
    std::cout<<"a is of type: "<<typeid(a).name()<<std::endl; // Output 'a is of type int'
    std::cout<<"b is of type: "<<typeid(b).name()<<std::endl; // Output 'b is of type someClass'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He's referring to a template parameter. If he knew the type he wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: he can use:
typeid(templateVariable).name();

Comment: Not if `templateVariable` is a template parameter.