# Differences between std::is_integer and std::is_integral?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, type-traits

C++11 provides two type trait template classes: `std::is_integer` and `std::is_integral`. However, I cannot tell the differences between them.

What type, say T, can make `std::is_integer<T>::value` true and make `std::is_integral<T>::value` false?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970485/is-integral-vs-is-integer-is-one-of-them-redundant/23970622

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`std::is_integer<T>` does not exist.

That being said, `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` does exist.

I'm not aware of any significant difference between `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` and `std::is_integral<T>`.  The latter was designed much later and became standard in C++11, whereas the former was introduced in C++98.

Comment: I do not see any answer to the question.

Answer (score 21):

There is no type `T` that has different results for `std::is_integral<T>::value` and `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer`. To quote the [draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf):

**3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]**

> 7 Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and
>   unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A
>   synonym for integral type is integer type.[...]

**18.3.2.4 numeric_limits members [numeric.limits.members]**

```
static constexpr bool is_integer;
```

> 17 True if the type is integer.

**20.9.4.1 Primary type categories [meta.unary.cat]** (table 47)

```
template <class T> struct is_integral;
```

> T is an integral type (3.9.1)

Answer (score 9):

`std::is_integral_v<T>` will only return true for built-in integers.

The standard allows `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` to be specialized and return true for custom integral types like `boost::multiprecion::cpp_int`.

Comment: I think that the `implementation-defined` in `Checks whether T is an integral type. Provides the member constant value which is equal to true, if T is the type bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, short, int, long, long long, or any implementation-defined extended integer types, including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants. Otherwise, value is equal to false.` means applications can inject specializations for `std::is_integral` the same way as for `std::numeric_limits`?

Comment: I am late to the party here. However, injecting specializations for std::is_integral is undefined behaviour:

Answer (score 1):

`std::is_integral<T>` and `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` are NOT the same. E.g. `boost::multiprecision` big ints are treated differently.

This is from a corresponding issue:

> `is_integral` returns information about the nature of the type and is
>   true only for "native" integer types, it should never be true for
>   class types. Which is to say `is_integer` and `is_class` are mutually
>   exclusive.
>
> `numeric_limits` on the other hand returns information on the
>   behaviour of a type - whether it models a particular concept if you
>   will - and so should be specialized for UDT's. Note that specializing
>   `is_integer` for UDTs would break code, since `is_integer` implies
>   that a lot of other things are also true like trivial move/copy/init
>   etc.

Comment: It seems that the quoted claim "Note that specializing is_integer for UDTs would break code, since is_integer implies that a lot of other things are also true like trivial move/copy/init etc" should read "specialize `is_integral`" instead?

Answer (score -2):

The difference is that `std::is_integral<T>` will only recognize decimal integers including `bool` `char` `char16_t` `char32_t` `wchar_t` `short` `int` `long` `long long`. While `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` will recognize all of those aswell as `float` `double`. Look at these two pages for more information: [is_integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_integer), [is_integral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)

Comment: If it behaved the way you suggest, it would not be very useful. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/c2cCLxwFlEKHsu1f