# is_integral vs is_integer: is one of them redundant?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

[is_integral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) and [is_integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_integer) seem to answer **the same thing in the same way**.

From the links to the related documentation pages, `is_integral` seems to be missing  specializations for the following types

```
signed char       
unsigned char     
unsigned short    
unsigned int      
unsigned long     
unsigned long long
```

Yet a [compiled example](http://ideone.com/86BbQg), shows (of course) their identical behaviour on those types as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << is_integral<signed char       >::value << endl;
    cout << is_integral<unsigned char     >::value << endl;
    cout << is_integral<unsigned short    >::value << endl;
    cout << is_integral<unsigned int      >::value << endl;
    cout << is_integral<unsigned long     >::value << endl; 
    cout << is_integral<unsigned long long>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So if they also behave the same, what was the point of introducing both of them in C++11?

**So if they also behave the same, what was the point of introducing both of them in c++11 ?**

### Edit : rephrasings

As [Useless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212858/useless) points out, the phrase *including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants* from the `is_integral` doc page reveals that even their specifications are a complete match.

Comment: _...seems to be missing some specializations..._ - you missed the sentence _"including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants."_ in your first linked page.

Comment: @Useless Yes, correct. That makes it even worse!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676574/differences-between-stdis-integer-and-stdis-integral

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` was *not* introduced by C++11. It was just updated to use the new `constexpr` qualifier.

`std::is_integral<T>` was introduced by C++11, and you're right it gives the same results. As to why it was added - possibly because the integral-ness or otherwise of a type isn't logically part of that type's `numeric_limits`?

It seems to be the goal of the `<type_traits>` header to gather all the type classification helpers in one place, while the older `numeric_limits` collects only properties specific to, well, numbers. If `numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` were deprecated, there'd be a slightly arbitrary boundary which type traits lived in `<type_traits>`, and which were considered numerical. It's hardly a terrible duplication to have it in both places.

Answer (score 5):

Noone has mentioned the point that `std::is_integral` follows the same style as the other C++11 UnaryTypeTraits of defining a single static data member called `value`. That allows it to be used interchangeably where any unary type trait is needed, for example:

```
template<typename Cond1, typename Cond2>
  using And = integral_constant<bool, Cond1::value && Cond2::value>;
```

You can't use `std::numeric_limits::is_integer` in the same way, because it doesn't follow the same conventions as the C++11 traits.

Splitting each trait into a single type with consistent names makes them more flexible than a trait that bundles several properties together with unpredictable names.

Answer (score 4):

Both are identical and will provide the same outputs.

However `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` exists since C98, not C++11, whereas std::is_integral was introduced as part of the C++11 type traits (`<type_traits>` header)

Edit:

As mentioned by @Useless , the reason of the introduction of std::is_integral is probably the desire to regroup all traits in `<type_traits>`.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1345.html) the original proposal to add `is_integral` to C++0x.

They make no reference of the overlap with `std::numeric_limits<>::is_integer`, but I'm assuming that the desire was simply to have all type traits in a single obvious place.